# why is my table screwing up my page?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter's bootstrap (I'm new to it) and have a menu and a table on the page. The menu by itself is fine. The table with no data (or just a few rows in it) is just fine. The problem is when I try to put a lot of rows in my table so that the vertical scroll bar appears, it messes up the formatting and the scrollbar bleeds into the header. Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ph7GZ/10). What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: 
This is what I'm currently getting:

```
______________________
|_______header_____|*| <----the scrollbar bleeds into the header
|                  |*|
|   Container Div  |*|
|                  |*|
|                  |*|
|                  |*|
|                  |*|
|                  |*|
----------------------
```

Here's what I want:

```
______________________
|_______header_______|
|                  |*|<--- scrollbar starts after the header
|   Container Div  |*|
|                  |*|
|                  |*|
|                  |*|
|                  |*|
|                  |*|
----------------------
```

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9P3X/1/) resolves the problem, but I can't seem to achieve the same with twitter bootstrap...the scrollbar still bleeds into the header. thx!

Comment: The scrollbar, I believe, has nothing to do with the table. It comes from the width set in the div classed container. See if it's true: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/Ph7GZ/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scrollbar, I believe, has nothing to do with the table. It comes from the width bootstrap sets on the .container div.

Take a look and see if you can still see the scroll-bar: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/Ph7GZ/3/

Comment: I will be having the vertical scroll bar, though.

Comment: I'll show you later today how to put the scrollbar only by the tables side. Im currently busy, sorry.